# GridView ImageView size in different screens

Tags: android, gridview

When I run my app on screen 4.3 it works fine but when I run on 3.14 screen, images don't show correctly one above the other in a big size.

Is there a way to show an image using percentage which depends on different screen sizes?

Here is the ImageView code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200 ));
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: here you are mentioning 200px not in dp. so for all res it will be 200 px only.

Comment: @Padma Kumar I can't write 200dp using this code and that's what I'm talking about

Comment: did you tried dmon answer that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution of my answer
it's close to @dmon answer

I created dimensions.xml in Values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="width">150dp</dimen>   
<dimen name="height">150dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and in imageadapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
            (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.width),                                                                                   
            (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height)));
    imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    return imageView;
}
```

thanks for everyone tried to help 
best regards

Comment: yes this your error line com.De7kat.Grid.ImageAdapter.<init>(ImageAdapter.java:20).

Answer (score 1):

//there is noting related with screen inch weather its an 4' or 3.2

its matters on screen resolution whether ldpi, mdpi,hdpi or xhdpi.

```
final int scaleImage=200;

// Get the screen's density scale
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
final int imgSize  = (int) (scaleImage * scale + 0.5f);

// Use imgSize as a distance in pixels...
this 200 will give you a pixel as 


@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imgSize,imgSize ));
        return imageView;
    }
```

- ldpi - 150px
- mdpi - 200px
- hdpi - 300px
- xhdpi- 400px

Comment: The method getResources() is undefined for the type 
  ImageAdapter

Comment: oh hoo you need to set the context.getResources().

Comment: @MohammadHammad post the crash log.

Comment: 09-07 12:47:17.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 12:47:17.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.De7kat.Grid/com.De7kat.Grid.De7katGrid}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 12:47:17.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
09-07 12:47:17.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
-=-=

Comment: Problem on these lines

 final int scaleImage=200;

 // Get the screen's density scale
 final float scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
 final int imgSize  = (int) (scaleImage * scale + 0.5f);
*/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get the screen dimensions

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

metrics.heightPixels;
metrics.widthPixels;
```

or this

```
getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels
getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dimens.xml file:

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="gridview">200dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then get that resource:

```
   int size = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gridview);
   imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));
```

You can read up on Dimension resources in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: Can you check the values of size with different devices? If they are adjusting correctly then there might be something else wrong with your code.